# Limit of Piecewise Linear Function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{llll}
 x-4k & {\rm if \,\,}  4k-1 \le x \le 4k+1\\
 -x+4k+2 & {\rm if \, \,} 4k+1 \le x \le 4k+3
 \end{array}  \right.$

where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. What about $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)$? And what about $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}$?

What is $\int_0^x f(x)$?

Comment: $f(4k+1)=?$... also what is $k$?

Comment: Note that $f$ oscillates between $-1$ and $1$ indefinitely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(x) \in [-1;1], \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$, so  $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x} = 0$

$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)$ doesn't exist since $f(4k-1)=-1$ and  $f(4k+1)=1$, $\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have added another question:

"What is $∫_0^x f(x)$?"

For that part, you should first calculate $∫_0^4 f(x)$ by separating it as $∫_0^1+∫_1^3+∫_3^4$,

and then write $x=4h+y, h\in\mathbb{Z}, y\in [0,4)$.